# MiddleWare vs CustomRequest for check user rights

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Let's say there some users who have several posts. Every user has many posts, and every post belongs to one user.
To change post frontend uses URL like `users/1/posts/3`. The goal is to check, that post number 3 belongs to user number 1.
There are several ways to do it:

1. Check inside controller method or service(bad method IMHO)
2. Check inside custom request (authorize function)
3. Check inside middleware

I choose between the last 2, but have some doubts. The custom request should contain validation rules and do not be linked with authorization(SOLID), and I don't know if it's good to do it inside middleware.

Comment: Side note: would suggest you to define routes with less variables in them. Like `users/{user}/posts`, `posts/{post}`

Comment: hmm, I've read some articles about REST API URL naming, and most of them propose this variant

Comment: lets say we have a user: 1 and user: 2. Can both of them have created post: 3? meaning so both `users/1/posts/3` and `users/2/posts/3` exist?

Comment: Understood your point of view, it makes sense, but REST is the rules bunch, generally accepted standard, and I will follow it

Comment: That's just unnecessary complexity, which does not serve any purpose for programming simplicity or later use of API. But anyone can decide what fits the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to check if user can modify the post.

For authorizing access https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies is a way to go.

After defining policy you can reuse it in blade files, in controller and etc..

The policy defines rules for standard actions like create, read, update, delete.

For blades then you can:

```
@can('update', $post)
```

For methods in controllers:

```
$this->authorize('update', $post)
```

For anywhere else:

```
$user->can('update', $post)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Policies in conjunction with custom Form Requests